# How to resize images properly on boostrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I cannot get these images chopped down to fit properly in the carousel. I think this line needs to be edited somehow:

IGNORE:
It is telling me to add more detail so im typing extra things to by pass it like a bad person would take the easy way out and not add actual info but rather some bs that adds no value to the post

Heres my shittily written code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
h1{
    color: aqua;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic; 

} 


</style>

<!-- this creates the menu -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mason Cox</a>
</div>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="Cox_Mason_jumbotron.html">Jumbotron</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="Cox_Mason_carousel.html">Carousel</a></li>
  <li><a href="Cox_Mason_responsive_table.html">Table</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
<!--this is the heading-->
<h1>Mason Cox</h1>

<!--this is the carousel-->
<div class="container">
<h2>Friends and I Carousel</h2>  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="leahandi.jpg" alt="dance"  style="width:75%;" 
   style="height:25%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>My girlfriend and I at a dance.</h3>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="padre.png" alt="padre" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Friends and I at a bar in South Padre</h3>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="homepage.PNG" alt="oldpic" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>A picture of me frshman year</h3>
      </div>
  </div>

    <div class="item">
    <img src="tailgate.jpg" alt="tailgate" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>My girlfriend and I at a tailgate.</h3>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="me.PNG" alt="topgolf" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>A picture of me at Top Golf</h3>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="friends.JPG" alt="friend group" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>A picture of friends and I from last year</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
 </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/88pf636q/) using test images from various sources AND these images are of different dimensions but they fit correctly within the carousel. Is this what you're looking for?

**Relevant code changes**:

```
div.carousel div.item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

If you take the above CSS out, you'll see how the carousel takes the size of the images within. By restricting the height to 300px, yes, the **large** images might seem blurry but pretty much good enough to fit within the carousel.

Let me know if this helps. If not, it'd be nice if you could provide the images as well.

IGNORE: image caption corresponding to the image. Makes NO sense.

Hope this works. :)

Comment: Awesome! Have fun!